# Laravel 7.5.2 $errors not displaying on blade

Tags: php, laravel

I followed the validation documentation on the Laravel site but the errors won't show on my blade template. Right now when i click submit it redirects back to the same page but no error is displayed. Also, I did run `dd($request->all());` and it displays data. I started learning Laravel like literally just started so I'll try my best to give you more info. :)

ContactFormController.php

```
namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use Illuminate\Support\MessageBag;
use App\Http\Requests;
use Mail;


class ContactFormController extends Controller
{
    public function create(){
        return view('pages.contact');  
    }

    public function store(Request $request){
        //dd($request->all());

        $this->validate($request, [
            'fname' => 'required',
            'email' => 'required|email',
            'message' => 'required'
        ]);

        Mail::send('emails.contactTemplate', [ 
            'msg' => $request->message
        ], function ($mail) use($request){
            $mail->from($request->email, $request->fname);
            $mail->to('cslim5515@gmail.com')->subject('New Enquiry'); 

        });

        return redirect()->back()->with('flash_message', 'Thank you for your message');
    }

    public function build()
{
    return $this->markdown('emails.contactTemplate');
}
}
```

contact.blade.php

```
<div class="card-body text-justify" style="font-size:14px">
                        <div class="">
                        @if ($errors->any())
                            <div class="alert alert-danger">
                                <ul>
                                    @foreach ($errors->all() as $error)
                                        <li>{{ $error }}</li>
                                    @endforeach
                                </ul>
                            </div>
                        @endif
                            <form action="{{ url('charge') }}" method="post">
                                @csrf
                                <div class="form-row mb-3 ">
                                    <label>Full Name</label>
                                    <input type="text" class="form-control" name="fname" />
                                    @error('fname')
                                        <div class="form-text invalid-feedback">Enter your full name</div>
                                    @enderror
                                </div>

                                <div class="form-row mb-3">
                                    <label>Email</label>
                                    <input type="text" class="form-control @error('email') is-invalid @enderror"
                                        name="email" />
                                    @error('email')
                                    <div class="form-text invalid-feedback">Enter your email addres</div>
                                    @enderror
                                </div>
                                <div class="form-row mb-3">
                                    <label>Mobile No.</label>
                                    <input type="number" name="mNo" class="form-control"/>
                                </div>
                                <div class="form-row mb-3">
                                    <input type="submit" value="Send" class="btn btn-success" />
                                </div>
                            </form>
                        </div>
                    </div>
```

Comment: Upon submit, and after the redirect, what do you see in the network response? Is status 422? What's in the response of that call?

Comment: @Digvijayi upon submit i got a 302 status

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I made a new Laravel project and copy and pasted the views and routes to the new Laravel project and make a new controllers again and it works. No changes to the code was made

Answer (score 0):

Please Try this

```
if ($validator->fails()) {
    return Redirect::back()->withErrors($validator);
}
```

Your method should be like

```
public function store(Request $request){

    $data = array(
            'fname' => $request->input('fname'),
            'email' => $request->input('email'),
            'message' => $request->input('message'),
            );

    $rule  =  array(
            'fname'       => 'required',
            'email'       => 'required',
            'message'     => 'required'
               ) ;

    $validator = Validator::make($data, $rule);

    if ($validator->fails()) {
        return redirect::back()->withErrors($validator);
    } else {
        Mail::send('emails.contactTemplate', [ 
            'msg' => $request->message
        ], function ($mail) use($request){
            $mail->from($request->email, $request->fname);
            $mail->to('cslim5515@gmail.com')->subject('New Enquiry'); 
        });

        return redirect()->back()->with('flash_message', 'Thank you for your message');
    }
}
```

Comment: I got a **Class 'App\Http\Controllers\Redirect' not found** and i searched for the solution online and i added `use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Redirect;` but i still got the same problem no changes

Comment: Please check code again. I have made some changes. Updated the redirect statement if validation fails

Comment: Still the same issue, btw i created a new laravel project and the current code i use worked, it displayed the error message but for some reason this laravel project has issues could it be i turned off something. idk